# On adding target(LambdaFunction) to Event Rule in AWS-CDK in java giving error: There is already a Construct with name lambda_name in stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

```
Function lambdaFun =
            Function.Builder.create(this, LAMBDA_NAME)
                    .runtime(Runtime.JAVA_11)
                    .code(LambdaCode)
                    .functionName(LAMBDA_NAME)
                    .handler("handler_xyz")
                    .role(role)
                    .memorySize(3008)
                    .timeout(Duration.minutes(15))
                    .environment(LAMBDA_ENV)
                    .build();
    Rule rule =
                Rule.Builder.create(this, CWE_NAME)
                        .schedule(Schedule.rate(Duration.seconds(60)))
                        .description("CloudWatch Event")
                        .build();

    rule.addTarget(new LambdaFunction(lambdaFun));
```

On doing this it's giving below error

```
Caused by: software.amazon.jsii.JsiiException: There is already a Construct with name 'lambda-name' in Stack
```

Don't know how to typecast Function to IRuleTarget or How to convert function to IRuleTarget object

Comment: currently using CDK version 1.45.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried namespacing or adding a prefix to your function name? That error sounds like it comes up if there is another lambda function with the same name in the same stack.

Comment: Your comment made my day, I was creating the Function in one block and was trying to add that in rule target in some another block, so calling both the blocks separately was creating two lambdas with the same name and giving the error.
I put the whole code in one block(function) and it's done!!